# LINQ2SQL: Using the parent ID in a child object twice - parent ID equals zero

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got the following code and I wish to set the AssignmentID and the ToDoAssignmentID to the same value. Setting AssignmentID to workOrder.AssignmentID works just fine, but setting ToDoAssignmentID to workOrder.AssignmentID results in ToDoAssignmentID being set to 0. Why is that?

```
workOrder.ClientID = this.Client.ClientID;
workOrder.AssignmentID = this.WorkOrderID;
workOrder.AssignmentNumber = this.GetNextWorkOrderNumber(this.Client);
workOrder.CustomerID = this._CustomerID;
workOrder.DateCreated = this.Created;
workOrder.DatoAvtaltStart = this.AgreedStart == DateTime.MinValue ? new DateTime().MinSDTValue() : this.AgreedStart;
workOrder.DatoAvtaltSlutt = this.AgreedEnd == DateTime.MinValue ? new DateTime().MinSDTValue() : this.AgreedEnd;
workOrder.DateStopped = this.Ended == DateTime.MinValue ? new DateTime().MinSDTValue() : this.Ended;
workOrder.CreatedByEmployeeID = this._CreatedByEmployeeID;
workOrder.ResponsibleEmployeeID = this._ResponsibleEmployeeID;
workOrder.KoordinatorAnsattId = this._CoordinatorEmployeeID;
workOrder.Description = this.Description;
workOrder.Notes = this.Notes;
workOrder.EstimertTimerFra = this.EstimatedHoursFrom;
workOrder.EstimertTimerTil = this.EstimatedHoursTo;
workOrder.EstimatedBillingDate = this.EstimatedBillingDate;
workOrder.Priority = (byte)this.Priority;
workOrder.OBS = this.OBS;
workOrder.CustomerReference = this.CustomersReference;
workOrder.InterntOrdrenr = this.InternalOrderNumber;
workOrder.EksterntOrdrenr = this.ExternalOrderNumber;
workOrder.AssignmentStatusID = this.WorkOrderStatusID;

foreach (var activity in this.Activities)
{
    var ProductID = 0;

    try
    {
        ProductID = activity.Product.ProductID;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    workOrder.Activities.Add(new Activity()
    {
        ActivityID = activity.ActivityID,
        ClientID = activity.Client.ClientID,
        AssignmentID = workOrder.AssignmentID,
        Description = activity.Description,
        Notes = activity.Notes,
        IsBillable = activity.Billable,
        Priority = (byte)activity.Priority,
        ActivityTypeID = activity.ActivityType.TypeID,
        PerformedByEmployeeID = activity.PerformedByEmployee.EmployeeID,
        ProductID = ProductID,
        ToDo = activity.IsPlanned,
        ToDoAssignmentID = workOrder.AssignmentID,
        ToDoCustomerID = workOrder.CustomerID
    });
}

workOrderContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Because the id for the entity hasn't been generated yet.

Comment: Then how come AssignmentID gets set to workOrder.AssignmentID but ToDoAssignmentID gets set to zero? The Activity-table is a child-table of the Assignment-table, which means that it should work afaik.

Comment: The WorkOrder.AssignmentID is initally also set to 0, but because it is the foreign key field it is once again updated by Linq-2-sql during the SubmitChanges()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is not to think database style, but ORM style.

So instead of setting keys, you assign entities.

so change

```
ToDoAssignmentID = workOrder.AssignmentID
```

to (most probable guess of tablenames, check the definition of your entity) the following assignment of entities

```
ToDoAssignment = workOrder
```

This will be handled during SubmitChanges as well.